# Add the values from checkboxes on Angular

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I have a doubt. I have some checkboxes that I want to add on a final input (`#equipamentoPunct`) to finally submit all the data:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label><h3>Equipamento</h3></label> <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" class="sumEq" value="14,28571429"> Equipo de sonido</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" class="sumEq" value="14,28571429"> Equipo de luces </label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" class="sumEq" value="14,28571429"> Ryder</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox4" class="sumEq" value="14,28571429"> Backline</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox5" class="sumEq" value="14,28571429"> Alquiler de equipos</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox6" class="sumEq" value="14,28571429"> Escenario</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox7" class="sumEq" value="0"> Camerinos 0</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox8" class="sumEq" value="4,76190476"> Camerinos 1 o 2</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox9" class="sumEq" value="14,28571429"> Camerinos 3+</label><br>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="equipamentoPunct">Puntuación Equipamento</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="equipamentoPunct" name="equipamentoPunct" [(ngModel)]="venue.equipamentoPunct">
</div>
```

I founded a lot of info about how to do it with vanilla JS or jQuery, but I have a lot of problems on angular. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got this right, you could do it like this:

In the template you can bind a method call to the **change** event of the input.

```html
<input type="checkbox" (change)="changeValue($event, 1)"> <span>1</span> <br/>
<input type="checkbox" (change)="changeValue($event, 1)"> <span>1</span> <br/>
```

While in the controller you can add/remove the value depending on wether the input is checked or not:

```js
  public totalValue = 0;

  public changeValue(event, value) {
    if (event.srcElement.checked) {
      this.totalValue += value;
    } else {
      this.totalValue -= value;
    }
  }
```

You can use the **totalValue** however you want.

You can find a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ema96r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)